# Is there a way to make the values in the list as columns in pandas? I am not looking to rename the columns, but add the list values as columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

this is my first question in this platform. Kindly correct me if I am wrong in any place.
My requirement is this.
I have a list of values as below.

a_list = ['a','b','c']

I am looking for ways to add the 'a','b','c' as columns in a dataframe.

Comment: `df.columns = a_list`?

Comment: or `pd.DataFrame(columns=a_list)` for a blank dataframe

Comment: I tried the df.columns = a_list and got this error
Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 3 elements